# Cambiar estilo de paginación al datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buenas devs ayúdenme por favor, como puedo cambiar el estilo de la paginación del datatable?? osea quiero poner pagination-sm pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo por que en la documentación de datatable no encuentro mucha información para poder hacerlo

**este es mi javascript**

```
$('.tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
    "ajax": "ajax/datatable_usuarios_ajax.php",
    "retrieve": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "processing": true,
    language: {
        "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla =(",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
        "sUrl": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Primero",
            "sLast": "Último",
            "sNext": "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        },
        "buttons": {
            "copy": "Copiar",
            "colvis": "Visibilidad"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: gracias por tu comentario, pero me refiero a que quiero añadir la clase pagination-sm pero no consigo la forma de hacerlo

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/52701/styling-the-pagination-element-with-bootstrap-4

Comment: Gracias compa logre hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar drawCallBack la cual se ejecuta cada vez que se dibuje la tabla y la paginación en el DOM, el ejemplo acontinuación está basado en lo que deseas hacer.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
         $('ul.pagination').addClass("pagination-sm");
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias hermano funciono sin problema porque al pasar de pagina volvia al estilo anterior pero ahora si se queda con la clase

Comment: Recuerda que datatables dibuja en el DOM cada vez que ejecutas un evento, por lo cual, añadirlo con un addClass de jQuery no es suficiente, es necesario mantener un seguimiento de los eventos, por lo cual drawCallback es perfecto para estos casos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero tengo una consulta que nadie pudo responderme igual sobre datatable, será que te puedo contactar por algún lado???

Comment: Claro, escríbeme en Twitter si gustas. https://twitter.com/BrayamValero O puedes hacer la pregunta por acá, como gustes.

Comment: No me deja enviarte mensajes en el Twitter